# VirtualBox error loading VM

Tags: virtualbox

Getting this error on a few of my VM's, but not all of them I have, all of them are windows VM's. Running VirtualBox (latest version as of this post date) on Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Google-fu has not been kind to me on this one. Anyone know what this error means and how to remedy it?

[image]

**Edit:**
It appears some of my images have been deleted! Yikes, not sure how that happened.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=44449) seems to have the exact same error, apparently...

> The problem was that the path to the .vdi files were missing.

Comment: Thanks but did not state how to fix the issue. Will try reinstalling, do I need to back up the vm images before I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, but you could move them away to be sure. Barely takes any time... :)

Comment: Turns out the path is correct, the images have been deleted, don't remember doing that...thanks Tom, your link led me to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you renamed your bots the paths of your bots changed but not the pointers to your snapshots.